# HTML E-Mail: images showing space in Gmail Android App

Tags: android, html, css, email, gmail

I'm making an *HTML* E-Mail. In the bottom of the E-mail *is the social media* - there has an white space pushing over the images.
I have checked it in other E-mail clients and it looks good. I've have seen the other stackoverflow questions about spacing and I've tried all those solutions as you can see in my *HTML* and *CSS* on the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2hRNk/. 
[image]

```
img{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Try add `border-collapse:collapse;` in your `table`property.

Comment: It didn't work Francisco Carvalho

Comment: I can't test that right now. Just try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/2hRNk/1/) changes. `img {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}`and those ones in Social Media `<th>` (_inline_ changes).

Comment: that almost worked. But, it's still double rowed like picture above and no more white spaces.

Comment: Can you please provide me a _printscreen_ to fast help?

Comment: I just printed another screen for you.

Answer (score 0):

try to use HTML  Tag for this .
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap

Comment: i think you don't need to use images for social media , just one image whet exsit all social , then you must be add code for image map <map name="footer-sep.png">
    <area id="@+id/area1001" shape="rect" coords="118,124,219,226" />
    <area id="@+id/area1002" shape="rect" coords="474,374,574,476" />
    <area id="@+id/area1004" shape="rect" coords="710,878,808,980" />
    <area id="@+id/area1005" shape="circle" coords="574,214,74" />
    <area id="@+id/area1006" shape="poly" coords="250,780,250,951,405,951" />